# Want to use a google maps intent to scrub for nearby restaurant infon

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Building an app in Android Studio and we want to be able to use an intent to search nearby restaurants to find ones that match out criteria. WE are students so we dont have the funds to pay for a google api key so we are trying to do this via an intent instead. basicaly we are havinga  user enter restaurant criteria and have google maps pick a random one that matches that criteria. any help (including thats not possible) would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `Intent` to launch Google Maps is a one way operation. You won't be able to get an `Intent` back with data.

Comment: Do you know of a way i can accomplish what I want?

Comment: In theory, you could start scraping data manually (with a server of your own making), but that will likely not be allowed by the terms of service from Google (so you could get blocked any time), and you'd be constantly fighting the changing website format/data.